# If $p>0$, then $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}\dfrac{1}{n^p} = 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functions

I am trying to find a simple proof. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\epsilon>0$. By Archimedian property, there is an $N>0$ such that $N>\frac{1}{\epsilon^{1/p}}$. Then, if $n\ge N$ we get $\frac{1}{n}\le\frac{1}{N}<\epsilon^{1/p}$. So 
$\left|\frac{1}{n^p}\right|=(\frac{1}{n})^p\le\left(\frac{1}{N}\right)^p<\epsilon^{p/p}=\epsilon$ if $n\ge N$.

Comment: @ sinbadh. Thanks !!!